# Is there a faster way of doing this average price loop?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a function that calculates the average price of something for the quantity I want.
Let's say this is my table:

```
Name:    Quantity:     Price:
Item A     10               1
Item A     20               2
Item A     20               3
Item A     20               4
```

If I want the average price of Item A for a quantity of let's say 35. I loop over the table and add up the quantity till $total is more than $quanity (and than break out), so that would be row 1, 2 and 3 in this case adding me up to a total of 50.

The average price of Item A is then (10x1 + 20 x 2 + 20 x 3) / 50 = 2,2 and this the output that I want.

But doing this is very heavy if you do this for alot of products.

Question:

Is there a way to do this thinking INSIDE the query that I use to output the above table.

Something like: 
`SELECT DISTINCT(Name) as item, SUM(quantity) as Howmuch, MIN(single) as Min
FROM Items
WHERE item = 'Item A'
  AND Howmuch > 30
ORDER BY single`?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: (1) Remember that you need to DISTINCT by the Item's name (average per item)
(2) You can use "as" in order to save the SUM() functions results

Comment: Can you explain the _meaning_ of this data first of all? Why is the same quantity of 20 in there with three different prices to begin with?

Comment: @misorude could be the same item sold from different websites

Comment: @misorude Yep, seems like a reasonable scenario to me.

Comment: *But doing this is very heavy if you do this for alot of products.* Can you demonstrate `doing this`?

Comment: Yes it is the same Item sold from different inputs. This is the heavy part:

`code    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($quantitycounter > $quantity) {
            break;
        }
        $quantitycounter = $quantitycounter + $row['quantity'];
        $price = $price + $row['buyout'];
        if ($counter == 0) {
            $return['minprice'] = $row['buyout'] / $row['quantity'];
        }
        $counter++;
    }
    $return['singleprice'] = round($price / $quantitycounter, 0); `

But it seems not logic to me to do it this way even tho it does what I want.

Comment: No clue how to format above post. Sorry

Comment: Do you have any column to order data?

Comment: But if you are purchasing the 35 cheapest, won't the avg price be below 2?  Namely  (10x1 + 20 x 2 + **5** x 3) / **35** ?  (This feels like something to do in the app, not SQL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use SUM OVER's, to calculate cumulative totals.
Then derive the average from that.

**Sample data:**

> ```
> create table Items
> (
>   Name varchar(30),
>   Quantity int,
>   Price decimal(16,2)
> );
>
> insert into Items 
> (Name, Quantity, Price)
> values
> ('Item A', 10, 1),
> ('Item A', 20, 2),
> ('Item A', 20, 3),
> ('Item A', 20, 4);
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> SELECT Name
> , MIN(CumPriceTotal)/MIN(CumQuantity) AS AvgPrice
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT Name
>   , SUM(Quantity*Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Price, Quantity) as CumPriceTotal
>   , SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Price, Quantity) as CumQuantity
>   FROM Items
> ) q
> WHERE CumQuantity >= 35
> GROUP BY Name
> ORDER BY Name;
> ```
>
> ```
> Name   | AvgPrice
> :----- | -------:
> Item A | 2.200000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=5fce540757e3ed75dc780cb9b70a6e64)*

Instead of using `GROUP BY` & `MIN`, using `ROW_NUMBER` to get the first could also work for this.
But I feel that a `GROUP BY` is more simple.

Comment: Amazing! This fixed it! Thanks

Comment: @Grumpymuppet Thx. Btw, I wasn't sure about what to order by in those window functions.  But if it should first sort by Quantity I'm sure you'll know what to change. :)